# Make dynamically generated list items a % height of the set parent height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have the following vertical tabs set up inside a fixed height parent div:

```
<div class="tabs-left">

  <ul class="nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Delete this tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Delete this tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Delete this tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Delete this tab</a></li>
  </ul>

  <a href="#">Add a tab</a>
</div>
```

Each `<li>` item is dynamic (They can be added or removed). The parent div `tabs-left` has a set height of 300px.

How do I (either with css or jquery) set the height of each tab to an equal shared % of the parent div above a certain number of tabs?

For example, with 4 tabs as illustrated they look nice with a max-height of about 50px, but when the number increases to say 10 tabs, i'd like the height to reduce equally to fit the parent div.

I realise with legibility in mind there's a limit to the number of tabs that can fit into a height of 300px, so then, the parent must scroll.

I've already tried `display: table-cell, display:block, height: auto` etc on the `li` items, with no joy.

If that makes sense, please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do something like this:

http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/ixmBq/

Which will count the list elements, work out how much space there is, then set all their heights correctly.  If you have more list elements added or removed, you just call the function after that has happened:

```
function work_out_height(){
  var li_count = $(".nav-tabs li").length;
  var li_height = parseInt($(".nav-tabs").height());
  var individual_height = li_height / li_count;
  console.log("count " + li_count)
  console.log("height " + li_height)
  console.log(individual_height)
  $(".nav-tabs li").each(function(){
    $(this).outerHeight(individual_height + "px");
  });
}

work_out_height();

$("#add").click(function(){
  var new_li = $(".nav-tabs li:first").clone();
  $(".nav-tabs").append(new_li);
  work_out_height()
})
```

#### Edit

You can add an extra bit to check, and if the li is getting too short, just fix it at whatever height is the preferable one.

http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/cKhny/

```
if(individual_height < smallest_height){
  individual_height = smallest_height;
  $(".nav-tabs").css({"overflow-y":"scroll"})
}else{
  $(".nav-tabs").css({"overflow-y":"hidden"})
}
```

Comment: This works almost perfectly. Is there a way of, when the height of each tab reaches that of the parent, it no longer reduces the height of each item? (and thus the parent just scrolls) ?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there are no way of doing this with css since the css would have to be aware of the number of li-elements and calculate a hight based on that, which it can not.

So here is a jQuery solution.

```
var tabs = $('.nav-tabs li');

if(tabs.length < 10){
    tabs.css('min-height', '50px')
}
else{
    var height = [desired height calculation];
    tabs.css('min-height', height + 'px')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of reference, I've managed to work it out with a function that calculates the height and applies **BOTH** a min-height as well as a max-height to the listitems before scrolling when there's too many items shown:

**JS:**

```
resizeTabs(30, 55);
function resizeTabs(minHeight, maxHeight) {
    var tabs = $('.nav-tabs li a');
    var containerHeight = $('.nav-tabs').height();
    var tabHeight = containerHeight/tabs.length;
    tabHeight = Math.min(maxHeight, Math.max(minHeight, tabHeight));
    tabs.outerHeight(tabHeight + 'px');
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">TAB</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">TAB</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">TAB</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">TAB</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">TAB</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">TAB</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My 'tabbable' div is now set with a px height and the listitem tabs work out themselves based upon that height. I've given a `margin-bottom:1px` to each tab too.

Thanks for everyone's contributions.